# Beginner in VB.net, lost with DLLs, DirectShow, AVIcap32.dll, and etc For Image Processing

Tags: vb.net, api, image-processing

Ultimate goal would be using VB.net to interface with webcam and do image processing.

Currently I'm just using Matlab, but it is insanely slow.  Since I'm going into the area of image processing,coupled with object recognition, which path should I go down to? This by meaning is it GDI+? DirectX? or some other APIs? What is the API that supports manipulating and analyzing graphical input data? By which I may go delve deeper, and create a standalone software just for my own interest/project.

Comment: Just download and read some pdf available in net. Here you need to ask questions when you stuck with an issue while developing. No one teaches how to do this.www.Codeproject.com is a site which you can get tutorials. Also use Msdn for introductions. Happy Programming.

Comment: So, I just need to familiarize myself with VB.net language first? After i know the syntax and such, what next? Thank You.

Comment: go to codeproject.com you can see different types of projects and tutorials. download and learn .

Answer (score 3):

Before going deep into digital image processing with VB.Net, I **strongly** suggest that you take your time to learn the basics first, after that moving on to the next step which is dealing with the APIs you mentioned.

However, to answer your question, API (Application Programming Interface) is a set of programming instructions and standards communicate your application with other applications.

Which basically allows two different pieces of software to speak to one another through a common interface.

As for the DLL (Dynamic link library) files, they are a set of executable functions or data that can be used by a Windows application.

Or as I quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library):

> Dynamic-link library (also written unhyphenated), or DLL, is Microsoft's implementation of the shared library concept in the Microsoft Windows and OS/2 operating systems. These libraries usually have the file extension DLL, OCX (for libraries containing ActiveX controls), or DRV (for legacy system drivers). The file formats for DLLs are the same as for Windows EXE files — that is, Portable Executable (PE) for 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, and New Executable (NE) for 16-bit Windows. As with EXEs, DLLs can contain code, data, and resources, in any combination.

Basically, you shouldn't go too deep while you are in the beginning and I strongly encourage you to start learning the language itself then, step by step until you master the language.

I would like to say something to you IvanWong....**Welcome to the world of programming, Fun and challenges!!!**

Comment: Lol. I can't seem to get around to understand how does all those stuff connects with VB. Because in microCs, everything I write can be translated to instructions to physical hardware manipulation. In VB.net, it becomes much more vast. I want to let's say write a code to pulse out PWM in microC, it's easy. But in VB.net, i want to write a code to read webcam inputs, I can find tutorials, but I want explanation.

Comment: oh! I see, here are some articles that will help you.

[VB and Webcam](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vbgeneral/thread/dd860b19-ea95-4701-9a5a-1fd7fab81c98), 

[Capture a Webcam Input](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/61783-capture-webcam/) and 

[Webcam Input Capture](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/30375)

**Edit:**
Consider MSDN (Microsoft Developer Network) for further and basic explanations of the concepts in the article in the links I provided